# Extract Median Value of composite but keep associated pixel data

Tags: google-earth-engine

How would one use `reduceRegions` to extract the median value pixel of an image band for a given set of polygons but also extract the corresponding band information of that median pixel.

For example, I have an image Max NDVI composite that has the following bands:

```
['NDVI_Max', 'Red','Blue','Green']
```

For a given polygon, I would like to extract the median 'NDVI_Max' value, but also extract that pixel's corresponding 'Red', 'Green' and 'Blue' values.

Below is the code I have but I'm stuck on how to adjust the reduce_Regions section:

```
// Creating the initial NDVI max composite with corresponding bands where img is my image collection.

var reducer = img.select('NDVI','B2','B3','B4').reduce(ee.Reducer.max(4)).rename(
                       'NDVI','B2','B3','B4'); 

// Reducing the image composite and extracting the median but it does it for all bands and using .select('NDVI') means I will lose the other bands. 

var stats = reducer.reduceRegions({
  collection: fc,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.median(),
  scale: 10  // meters  
});
```

Here is the sample code I've worked on:

[Code Sample](https://code.earthengine.google.com/af6b6903a1d7fce6b9e80eb6e3393dd2)

Comment: Hi there! Could you provide a working example? Currently the code you provided is not enough to test the code.

Comment: @M.Nicolas I've edited the original post to include the code sample. Thanks for any advice you can provide!

Comment: Great, almost there, now you only need to make your asset 'users/lbhajan/i15_Crop_Mapping_2018' available

Comment: @M.Nicolas Apologies - it is shared now. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Do you want to extract a mean value for all images in the original imageCollection, or one value per image in the imageCollection?

Comment: For anyone interested this was solved: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/438907/extract-specific-pixels-values-in-all-bands-of-multiband-image?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to go about this problem, depending on the specifics of what you are trying to obtain. If I understood correctly, you are trying to:

1. Get the spatial average of the maxNDVI within each feature intersecting your maxNDVI image.
2. Within the same feature from which you have extracted the mean(maxNDVI), you want to join the mean(medianRGB) values within the same feature.

This can be done very simply by using combined reducers like this:

```
var reducers = ee.Reducer.max().combine({
  reducer2: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  sharedInputs: true
});

var reducedImg = img.reduce(reducers).select('NDVI_max','B2_mean','B3_mean','B4_mean');

// Extracts the median (Max NDVI value) per region 

var dict = reducedImg
  .reduceRegions({
    collection: yolo_almond,
    reducer: ee.Reducer.median(),
    scale: scale
  });
print('dict',dict);
Map.addLayer(dict);
```

However, if this is not what you meant, then the approach may vary significantly, so please do confirm or not if this was the expected result. If not please be more specific on what exactly is the format of the expected output.

Link to code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/48dc1d396cd3a569f78e937b30f91e2f

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think this is close to what I want but not exactly it. Let me rephrase:

From the Max NDVI Composite, I would like to use Zonal Statistic/Reduce Regions to calculate the Median (Max NDVI) Value for a given feature (polygon). 

Additionally, I would like to extract the corresponding band information for that Median (Max NDV) Value i.e. that pixel's corresponding Red, Green and Blue values, not the feature's median Red Green and Blue value.