# Extract specific pixel's values in all bands of multiband image

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, zonal-statistics

Earlier related post here: ([Extract Median Value of composite but keep associated pixel data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/435835/extract-median-value-of-composite-but-keep-associated-pixel-data/436125#436125))

Reposting for additional clarity and refined question.

Datasets: Multiband Image with bands `['NDVI', 'Red','Blue','Green']` and FeatureCollection of farm boundaries.

In Earth Engine, I have been using `reduceRegions` together with `ee.Reduce.median()` to extract the Median NDVI value per feature in my FeatureCollection. However, I would also like to extract, per feature, the associated band values of that specific **extracted NDVI median pixel** i.e. the 'Red', 'Green' and 'Blue' values of the Median NDVI Pixel.

From my understanding `ee.Reducer.median()` will extract the median value in all bands per feature.

To solve this, I used `ee.Reducer.median()` to extract the median value, then create a mask for that value, theoretically masking all other pixels in that features area. Then I would be able to extract using any `reducer` given that there should only be 1 unmasked pixel for this area.

1. However, how does Earth Engine calculate the median when there is an even number of pixels in a given feature?

Link to code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/7460d06de0bbffe5f7d32d5a1ec4f005

Comment: Median of `1, 3` is `2`. So there might actually not be a pixel with that value. You have to find the pixel with a value closest to the median (there might be multiple with the same distance, of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to compute the distance from the median for each pixel in each polygon, and then use the `numInputs` option on the `min` reducer to bring along the other bands for the pixel with the smallest difference.

```
var bands = ee.List(['NDVI','B1','B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7','B8',
                      'B8A','B9','B11','B12','GNDVI',
                      'NDVI_RE1','DOY'])

// Creates Max NDVI pixel composite and attaches corresponding band data at pixel level.
var maxComposite = data.select(bands).reduce(ee.Reducer.max(16)).rename(bands)

// Extracts the median (Max NDVI value) per region 
var medianNDVIperFeature = maxComposite.select('NDVI').reduceRegions({
  collection: yolo_almond,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.median(),
  scale: 10  // meters  
});

// Compute the difference from the median for each pixel.
var difference = medianNDVIperFeature.reduceToImage(['median'], ee.Reducer.first())
      .subtract(maxComposite.select('NDVI'))
      .abs()
      .rename("difference")

// Get the pixel in each region with the smallest difference.
var closestSpectraPerRegion = difference.addBands(maxComposite)
    .reduceRegions({
        collection: yolo_almond,
        reducer: ee.Reducer.min(17).setOutputs(ee.List(["difference"]).cat(bands)),
        scale: 10  // meters  
    })
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/857e038823293e259cf17e666a8c0640

Comment: I ran the code and am a little confused as to why the 'difference' band for `closestSpectraPerRegion.first()` would show as `null`?

Also in this case would it make sense to reorder the bands so that `difference` is first band since we want to get the associated pixel values in all bands based on the minimum difference from the median not the median `NDVI`. After reordering then run the `ee.Reducer.min` reducer?

Comment: oops, two issues.  First one is that the median value in the features is named "median", not 'NDVI', we the reduceToImage isn't doing anything (and you were just getting the min NDVI value in each polygon).  Second, you're correct; the band to minimize should be first.  Code corrected.